# Django-CMS Child plugin to show filtered data from DB table

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have two plugins ProductSelector(parent) and SpecificationSelector(child). I want to set the child up so that when you add it to the parent the Specifications that are shown are the only ones for the product (parent). Right now it pulls in all the specifications from the table. These lines let me filter the data to get what I want.

**edit: I found an error that i fixed in the code. I had the PluginBase names the same as the model. This allowed me to use ProductSelector.objects.get(cmsplugin_ptr=instance.parent) in the child to get the parent instance. I still need to figure out how to pass the filtered specification list to the "PluginAdmin Interface"**

```
    product = ProductSelector.objects.get(cmsplugin_ptr=instance.parent)
    specification = Specifications.objects.filter(product_name__product_name__iexact = product.product_name)
```

However, I haven't figured out how to send that filtered list to the plugin admin interface.

```
class ProductSelectorPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ProductSelector
    name = "Product Selector"
    render_template = "product_selector.html"
    allow_children = True
    child_classes = ['SpecificationSelectorPlugin'] 

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):

        context['instance'] = instance
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(ProductSelectorPlugin)

class SpecificationSelectorPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = SpecificationSelector   
    render_template = "specification_selector.html"
    formfield_overrides = {models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple},}

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        product = ProductSelector.objects.get(cmsplugin_ptr=instance.parent)
        specification = Specifications.objects.filter(product_name__product_name__iexact = product.product_name)
        context['instance'] = instance
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(SpecificationSelectorPlugin)
```

models.py

```
class ProductSelector(CMSPlugin):
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, help_text = "Select the product you want to place")
    new_product = models.BooleanField(blank=True)


class SpecificationSelector(CMSPlugin):
    specification = models.ManyToManyField(Specifications, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return unicode(self.specification)
```

Here is an screenshot the Django-cms plugins in the placeholder. Currently it is showing all specs in the table, but I just want it to be the specs for that particular product.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQsO5.jpg

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: can you post your models.py as well?

Comment: @Paulo I edited it to show the models for the plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMSPluginBase` inhertis from `ModelAdmin` which means that you can override the form rendered when adding and editing your plugin.

So you can create a `ModelForm` subclass like so:

```
class SpecificationSelectorPluginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpecificationSelectorPluginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.parent_id:
            # Assume that the parent is a product instance
            parent_plugin = self.instance.parent
            product = parent_plugin.get_plugin_instance()[0]

            if product:
                # It's possible that product is an orphan plugin.

                specifications = Specifications.objects.filter(
                    product_name__product_name__iexact=product.product_name)
                self.fields['specification'].queryset = specifications
```

then change your `SpecificationSelectorPlugin` to use this form like so:

```
class SpecificationSelectorPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    form = SpecificationSelectorPluginForm
```

The above will only work if the specification plugin is a **direct** child of the product plugin.

Comment: Awesome thanks Paulo. This works perfectly. I did click the up vote but because my reputation is below 15 it won't change it. But for anyone reading this, this is a great answer and very useful.